# 1960s or 1970s movie about first stage of alien invasion

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, alien-invasion

At a remote US Air Force radar station in the Arctic, the lone airman/engineer on duty is surprised by the arrival of a group of people, and lets them in. Our hero eventually realises that they are the advance party of an alien invasion force, when one of them partly removes their human mask/body suit, revealing an intense light within. The aliens try to stop him from warning his superiors, and he manages to barricade himself into a room. He taps out a Morse code message using wires from some equipment, which is received by two other airmen at another Air Force station. When one of the airmen interprets the message, it is a request for an immediate nuclear strike on the Arctic radar station. They ignore it, and the movie ends.

Comment: Welcome Arbeiter2, please enjoy our [tour] and read-up in the [help] about how we work. If you want to merge your previous account (if you were Arbeiter) then click on the "contact" button at the bottom of any page and explain the situation, a member of staff will sort it out for you next (working) day.

Comment: https://youtu.be/T5dwbZKd64Y

Comment: Honestly this sounds more like a TV episode rather than a move. Twilight Zone, Outer Limits perhaps.

Comment: You may be right. It was possibly a TV movie, rather than a cinematic release.